# Is it possible to restore a Joomla 2.5 backup on a new Joomla 3.7 server using akeeba

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have my web site running on Joomla 2.5.22, I made backup using Akeeba but I didn't make backup from Cpanel (I mean zipping all these files in cPanel).

Now I have to move to a new server and decide to upgrade to Joomla 3.7.1.
The backup (the JPA file) is already in the new server.

What should I do now? 
- Should I kickstart it using Akeeba kickstart and upgrade it
- or should I install a new Joomla 3.7.1 first and restore my backup of joomla 2.5.22 on it.

I'm afraid of the second solution to work well !!!

Please I need suggestion what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.

When you restore a backup made with Akeeba Backup, you are basically installing a new site which already contains your content and extensions.

If the webspace already contains a J3.7 site, that site is going to be overwritten (and in fact it may create troubles to have mixed files from different versions of Joomla, so it's probably best to clean up the webspace first).

You should just restore the J2.5 site, by using the `kickstart` tool from Akeeba.

After you are finished successfully and your J2.5 site is running fine on the new hosting, you can upgrade Joomla to 3.x following the guide https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, So If I understand you well, I need to kickstart the Joomla 2.5 backup on the new server using akeeba kickstart, and then upgrade it to 3.7.1.  Please confirm before I do that.

Comment: in addition, should I create a new database name and username/password in cPanel? or not?

Comment: Thanks, it's finally restored !

Comment: @Chloe yes you have to restore first, make sure everything is fine, and then upgrade. I updated my answer to make it more clear. Also take care of planning the upgrade carefully, you have to make sure all extensions are compatible with J3 or can be upgraded as well. Read carefully the linked document before doing anything.

Comment: Thanks. I did it already. There's a small issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409575/joomla-restored-backup-doesnt-display-images?noredirect=1#comment75821389_44409575) after restoration. Please maybe you can help too.